# Can the effect of instance on points be matched with geometric proximity to control materials?

Tags: materials, node-editor

It can be very simple to just make meshes in geometric nodes and then give them materials, but instantiation seems to be a bit complicated.

Randomization is also feasible, but there is no idea about how to use the data from the geometric node to the material node.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]